# Real word example of the probability my son would be in a class with a friend at school

Tags: probability

I have a real world example that is beyond my math skills.  Hoping this community can help.

My son's grade school feeds into 2 high schools.  Unfortunately most of the children attend the high school not in our district.  What is the probability that my son will still see someone he knows at his high school?  I think it's statistically unlikely.

The High School will have 700 freshmen students
35 of them will come from his prior school
of which he may recognize 33% (so round to 12)
of which he may have only spoken to 50% (so 6)

There are 7 classes in a day with 18 students in each class (so 39 classes during each period).  What is the chance that he'd be in one class as one of those other 5 students (note: it's not important if those other 5 students have classes with each other)?

I think it's more than figuring out the probability of one class student pairings and multiplying it by 7 classes.  Because that would assume all 6 students take the same class subjects in the same order, but if my son takes math first and student B took English first - there would be 2 periods that they cannot be in the same class.  So the potential schedules would also have to be taken into account - I think for this example we can assume they all take the same 7 classes (ie: not worry about advanced vs remedial courses, and assume they all took the same elective, etc).

Comment: I don't think any of the normal assumptions of probability (note: independence) apply. Just ask the neighbors. Or, better yet, encourage your son by telling him all the other kids will be just as scared as him to be in a new school, and he can make new friends.

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV. Do you want help to figure this out or just the solution?

Comment: I'd like more than the answer.  I'd at least like to understand the solution, so I can tweak it if I get new data.

Comment: Something more than "42" being the answer to life and the meaning of the universe (movie/book reference).

Comment: Interesting question ! I have twins who will be going to high school in september !! One initial question: would he really only recognise 1 in 3 of his current class mates ? (maybe not been at the school long?)

Comment: The thought of 1/3 was based on this.  His current school has 470 kids.  They are separated into 3 teams. Each team has a couple dedicated hallways and share the same group of teachers.  There is no interaction with other teams.  

Now I know he knows a couple kids from other teams from prior years, but I also doubt he would recognize everyone from his team too.  That's 150 or more kids.